# Flutter Layout: How to get focus inside a textformfield wrapped on a Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I have this Container with a specific decoration border, and as a child I have the TextFormField with another styled border using the parameter `enabledBorder`.

My problem is: I have to make a double click to show the cursor and be able to write on my textformfield, because the focus only gets the container decoration and do not gets the focus from the inside of my TextFormField.

Here is my code:

```
         onFocusChange: (focus) {
           print(focus);
         },
         child: Focus(
           child: Container(
             decoration: _focusNode.hasFocus && widget.errorText == null
                 ? BambamShadows.dropShadowSelected()
                 : null,
             child: TextFormField(
               cursorColor: BambamColors.brandBlack,
               focusNode: _focusNode,
               inputFormatters: widget.inputFormatters,
               enabled: widget.enabled,
               onChanged: widget.onChanged,
```

How can I get both Focus inside Container and TextFormField?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this package @ https://pub.dev/packages/indexed it'll grant you the same equivalent property that Z-index has in CSS which will allow you to position elements in a stack based on the index; so based on your question if your txtformField has a higher index it wouldn't be "below" the container (if that makes sense);

Also you can always consider modifying your UI to focus on using Stack (very good documentation about it here: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/stack-and-positioned-widget-in-flutter-3d1a7b30b09a)

I'd try indexed, else I'd clone your current java to implement a stack UI structure and test different variants till you nail it;

Comment: Those solutions doesn't work for me. Still trying to figure out how force the focus inside the textformfield without make two clicks on the screen

Comment: Hmm so index may not be it, can you kindly check if you've tried this method: https://codewithandrea.com/tips/easily-move-focus-scope-node/

Comment: Hmm the point is: my focus does not work properly because my textformfield is wrapped inside my container, I and need the decoration of this container for the business rules. 

Not even this documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/focus worked because is it assumes that my focus changes by another button and not from the element itself. Not sure if I was clear but that's it

Answer (score 0):

Try this `autofocus: true,` autofocus is a property in TextFormField class